# Changing Toolbar's Back Button Programmatically is lost on Android when a page is popped

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.forms, freshmvvm

XF 2.5 with FreshMVVM 2.2.3

I am calling a dependency service when pushing a new page to update back button colour as such:

```
FormsAppCompatActivity activity = (FormsAppCompatActivity)CrossCurrentActivity.Current.Activity;
Toolbar toolbar = activity.FindViewById<Toolbar>(Resource.Id.toolbar);
toolbar?.NavigationIcon?.SetColorFilter(foregroundColour.ToAndroid(), PorterDuff.Mode.SrcIn);
```

Then I am losing my new colour changes on Android only when I pop the previous page (that is not showing anymore).

- If I don't pop the previous page, then the colour stays as expected
- If I set the colour after the pop, that doesn't work
- If I set the colour in the Init of the new page, that doesn't work
- If I set the colour in the `ViewIsAppearing` (FreshMVVM) of the new page, that doesn't work
- If I set the colour after two seconds on the Init of the new page using   `Device.StartTimer` then that works!

My hunch is that I need to find a later event to set the colour but I am not sure there is one after `ViewIsAppearing`

Any suggestion on how to make the back button colour change permanently?

Comment: I didn't use FreshMVVM, but if you need change the `NavigationIcon`, you could refer to my answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47323343/how-to-change-navigation-page-back-button-in-xamarin-forms/47363401#47363401