# How to change the toolbar back icon in xamarin forms android

Tags: c#, android, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am working on **xamarin** forms. I wanted to change the `Toolbar` back icon how to do it. I searched lot about it. I didn't get proper solution. Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks
praveen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
    LoadApplication(new App());

    var upArrow = Resources.GetDrawable(Resource.Drawable.abc_ic_ab_back_mtrl_am_alpha);
    upArrow.SetColorFilter(Resources.GetColor(Resource.Color.white), PorterDuff.Mode.SrcIn);
    ActionBar.SetHomeAsUpIndicator(upArrow);
```

References

https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/57791/cant-change-android-back-button-in-xamarin-forms

https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/103317/change-navigation-bar-back-button-color-in-xamarin-android

Comment: @Gowhtanman M, Thanks for the reply. But i am using toolbar like below. Android.Support.V7.Widget.Toolbar toolbar
               = this.FindViewById<Android.Support.V7.Widget.Toolbar>(Resource.Id.toolbar);
            SetSupportActionBar(toolbar);

Comment: I need to change the Toolbar navigation back icon. If i use actionbar, I will get exception.

Comment: here is the answer check it bro...https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47323343/how-to-change-navigation-page-back-button-in-xamarin-forms?rq=1

Comment: Apply custom theam into your toolbar

Comment: I got solution for listen the navigationbar back icon click. For that i was looking for change the icon.

Comment: Second solution works. I was created Page renderer class inside mainactivity. if we use page renderer in mainactivity it will not work.We should create separate class for that. Thanks bro for make me more focus on the solution.

Answer (score 0):

> How to change the toolbar back icon in xamarin forms android

You could refer to my answer: [How to change navigation page back button in xamarin forms.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47323343/how-to-change-navigation-page-back-button-in-xamarin-forms/47363401#47363401)

I write it here again:

**We need to custom a `NavigationPageRenderer`, override the `OnPushAsync` method to set the `Toolbar`'s navigation icon.**

```
using AToolbar = Android.Support.V7.Widget.Toolbar;
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(CustomNavigationPage), typeof(NavigationPageRendererDroid))] // APPCOMP
...
public class NavigationPageRendererDroid : Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.AppCompat.NavigationPageRenderer // APPCOMP
{
    public AToolbar toolbar;
    public Activity context;

    protected override Task<bool> OnPushAsync(Page view, bool animated)
    {
        var retVal = base.OnPushAsync(view, animated);

        context = (Activity)Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Context;
        toolbar = context.FindViewById<Android.Support.V7.Widget.Toolbar>(Droid.Resource.Id.toolbar);

        if (toolbar != null)
        {
            if (toolbar.NavigationIcon != null)
            {
                toolbar.NavigationIcon = Android.Support.V4.Content.ContextCompat.GetDrawable(context, Resource.Drawable.Back);
                //toolbar.SetNavigationIcon(Resource.Drawable.Back);
            }
        }
        return retVal;
    }
}
```

The `CustomNavigationPage` are defined in `PCL` :

```
public class CustomNavigationPage : NavigationPage
{
    public CustomNavigationPage(Page startupPage) : base(startupPage)
    {
    }
}
```

Usage :

```
public App()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    MainPage = new CustomNavigationPage(new MainPage());
}
...
// In MainPage
private async void Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    await Navigation.PushAsync(new TestPage());
}
```

**[Effect].**

[image]