# Editing the NavigationPage back button size in xamarin forms

Tags: user-interface, xamarin

My aim is to change increase the size of the back arrow button that comes with the NavigationPage class. I have found out that we are able to change its color, but not it's size. Is it possible to do that in xamarin forms or can i atleast use a custom icon there that will suit my UI requirements.

```
 <Style TargetType="NavigationPage">
        <Setter Property="BarTextColor" Value="Red" />
        <Setter Property="BarBackgroundColor" Value="Black" />
      
  </Style>
```

Here i am able to set color for the "BarTextColor" but not it's size. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NavigationPage back button is icon, so you can replace this icon using another bigger icon.

For Android platform, if your `MainActivity` type is `FormsAppCompatActivity`, you could custom a `PageRenderer` and change the `Toolbar's` `NavigationIcon`.

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(ContentPage), typeof(NavigationPageRendererDroid))]
namespace FormsSample.Droid
{
public class NavigationPageRendererDroid : PageRenderer
{
    public NavigationPageRendererDroid(Context context) : base(context)
    {

    }
    protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Xamarin.Forms.Page> e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged(e);

        var context = (Activity)this.Context;
        var toolbar = context.FindViewById<AndroidX.AppCompat.Widget.Toolbar>(Droid.Resource.Id.toolbar);

        toolbar.NavigationIcon = AndroidX.Core.Content.ContextCompat.GetDrawable(context, Resource.Drawable.c1);
        
    }
}
 }
```

Please note: ToolBar in Android platform> Resource folder> Layout type is `androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar`

If your ToolBar is other type, you can take a look:

[How to change navigation page back button in xamarin forms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47323343/how-to-change-navigation-page-back-button-in-xamarin-forms)

**Update:**

I also reproduce the same problem as you, from I provide the thread , you can follow the last solution, custom a NavigationPageRenderer, override the OnPushAsync method to set the Toolbar's icon.

Firstly, create a class named CustomNavigationPage in the .NET Standard project, and this class inherits from NavigationPage to make our custom renderer applied to that class.

```
 public class CustomNavigationPage : NavigationPage
{
    public CustomNavigationPage(Page startupPage) : base(startupPage)
    {

    }
}
```

Secondly, in Android project, create class named NavigationPageRenderer, override the OnPushAsync method.

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(CustomNavigationPage), typeof(NavigationPageRenderer))]
namespace FormsSample.Droid
{
public class NavigationPageRenderer : Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.AppCompat.NavigationPageRenderer
{     
    public Activity context;

    public NavigationPageRenderer(Context context) : base(context)
    {

    }
    protected override Task<bool> OnPushAsync(Page view, bool animated)
    {
        var retVal = base.OnPushAsync(view, animated);

       var context = (Activity)this.Context;
       var toolbar = context.FindViewById<AndroidX.AppCompat.Widget.Toolbar>(Droid.Resource.Id.toolbar);

        if (toolbar != null)
        {
            if (toolbar.NavigationIcon != null)
            {
                toolbar.NavigationIcon = AndroidX.Core.Content.ContextCompat.GetDrawable(context, Resource.Drawable.c1);
                toolbar.Title = "back";
            }
        }

        return retVal;
    }
}
}
```

Finally, in App.xaml.csfile, set the MainPage to NavigtaionPage,

```
  MainPage = new CustomNavigationPage(new simplecontrol.Page41());
```

Comment: Thanks for that idea. But do you think there is a way to update the default/native back icon to a larger size? my toolbar is `android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar`  and i used the solution from your link. While navigating through pages, the default icon appears for a fraction of a second and disappears once the page is fully loaded, and when i navigate back it reverts back to the default icon completely.

Comment: Hi, 
any update on how to overcome the above mentioned issue?. Thanks

Comment: @Hari default/native back icon is one image, it is not text or other, if you make this icon or image larger, you still need to replace the default. About another problem, please see my update.